# Is there a way of converting typescript definitions to C#, for use in Bridge?

Tags: c#, typescript, cross-compiling

Is there a way of converting typescript definitions to C#, for use in Bridge?

Like if I have:

```
class L
{
    value():string;
}
```

it would convert to:

```
class L
{
    public string Value ();
}
```

Comment: You can try this: https://github.com/michaelcheers/TypeScriptToCS

Comment: Retyped now does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try TypedocConverter, which can be used as a TypeScript to C# converter.

https://github.com/hez2010/TypedocConverter

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way of converting typescript definitions to C#

This is a non-goal of the TypeScript team so any solution will have to come from the community. A quick search shows exactly what you are asking for : https://github.com/michaelcheers/TypeScriptToCS

Comment: That project not only requires a depreciated .Net version, but also crashes at line 315 in "MTypescriptParser.cs".  I've tried several different typescript files before giving up.